# samsung ls32ag32x "not optimum mode, recommended mode 1920x1080 144Hz"

Tags: laptop, display, hdmi, external-display, usb-c

I recently got a brand new Samsung ls32ag32x monitor, The monitor works fine but it doesn't work with my USBc->HDMI connector, I have 3 laptops (MacBook m1 pro, m1 air and Dell XPS). when I connect to the screen using the USBc->HDMI dongle I get "not optimum mode, recommended mode 1920x1080 144Hz", but the M1 pro has an HDMI port so connecting directly works well with the monitor. I also have an MSI Optix MAG342CQR monitor and this works fine with this USBC->HDMI dongle so I can tell the dongle is not bad

[the USBc->HDMI dongle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXSpt.jpg)

[The error it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMnO3.jpg)

[My laptop connected directly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcx7d.jpg)

The issue now is I cannot use the other laptops with this monitor and they are my primary work laptops. Please who can help me with a possible solution here.

Comment: Which resolution are you using now? If you use the OCR/menu button of the monitor, do you see anything, and does the message return once you close the menu?

Comment: Can you go into the display settings on the Mac and configure the second display? https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh40768/mac The Macs might be expecting you to use 4K displays and not detecting the best settings for other monitors, the solution would likely be manually configuring the display yourself per that link.

Comment: Are you sure your laptop is sending 1920x1080 to the additional display? The correct way to check this is to go to system preferences > displays > then select the attached monitor in the list of displays, then make sure the *correct* scaling box is selected. If the wrong scaling box is selected then you could be outputting a resolution too high or too low for that monitor when the adapter is in use. Try all the available scaling boxes and see what gives good or bad results.

Comment: Hi, so I cannot change the resolution setting on my Mac when the monitor is connected to the dongle. But I bought a new dongle and it works now. Thanks to everyone who responded.

Comment: Thanks to everyone that responded, I did multiple troubleshooting, it didn't work, so I left it, bought a new dongle and it works fine with the new dongle.